# CS0246 error on first part of name in using clause

Tags: c#, namespaces, using, partial

In a simple console app used to test a couple of API's, I am getting a `"CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IFS' could not be found."` error.

[image: Error messages]

The strange thing is that the errors are on the 'using` clauses

[image: Code]

and is about not finding the first part of the name in that clause.

The assembly, with the same name as in the first using clause, is referenced. And it's root name space is set to `IFS.EOI.ETL'

[image: Library's root name space]

AFAICT with all this the console project is set up as it should be. So what could be causing the compiler to barf at it like this?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to have been caused by a mismatch in the targeted frameworks. The console project was targeting `.Net 4.5.2`, while the library was targeting `.Net 4.6.1`.

After changing the properties of the console project to target `.Net 4.6.1` as well, the compiler stopped complaining.